# Conditional probability: $P(B'|A) = 1-P(B|A)$

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are events with $P(A) > 0$. Show that $$P(B'|A) = 1-P(B|A),$$ where $B'$ is the complement of $B$.

I get stuck after I go from $P(B'|A)$ to $P(AB')/P(A)$. I would greatly appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

Using the fact that $P(B'A)+P(BA)=P(A)$, you get
$$P(B'|A)+P(B|A)=\frac{P(B'A)+P(BA)}{P(A)}=\frac{P(A)}{P(A)}=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

$1-P(B|A)$

=$1-\frac{P(B \cap A)}{P(A)}$

=$\frac{P(A)-P(B \cap A)}{P(A)}$

=$\frac{P(B' \cap A)}{P(A)}$

=$P(B'|A)$

Note that $P(A)=P(A\cap B)+P(A \cap B')$ since they are disjoint.